# Angular getting response body

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble understanding how one is supposed to get the response body from an Angular Response object. In their docs they have an example that states

`http.request('my-friends.txt').subscribe(response => this.friends = response.text());`

yet when I attempt to do `let body: string = response.text();` I get an error saying "Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'".

I tried treating it as a promise and doing

`let body: string;
 response.text().then(text => body = text);`

which removes the compilation error, but when this code gets invoked it throws and error saying "TypeError: response.text(...).then is not a function".

I would like to understand what exactly a Promise is and how I need to retrieve it's properties.

Comment: update the post with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've referenced the wrong `Response` object in your imports. If you're specifying the type need to import [Response](https://angular.io/api/http/Response) object from Angular package:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http`;
```

There is also [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object from fetch API supported natively by browsers. They differ in that Angular `Response` object returns `string` for `Response.text()` method, while fetch API `Response` returns a promise. The `http` service uses Angular's `Response` object and it returns a string so you don't need a promise here.

If you want to save the body text to the `body` variable, you have to do it when you get the value from an observable:

```
http.request('my-friends.txt').subscribe((response: Response) => this.body = response.text());
```

Comment: Yup, that's the case. I had no idea there was another Response. Thanks for the clarification.